# GCM Service for android shows java.net.UnknownHostException: android.googleapis.com

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Code for the GCMService:

```
package com.avilyne.gcm;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.google.android.gcm.server.Message;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.MulticastResult;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class GCMBroadcast
 */
@WebServlet("/GCMBroadcast")
public class GCMBroadcast extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // The SENDER_ID here is the "Browser Key" that was generated when I
    // created the API keys for my Google APIs project.
    private static final String SENDER_ID = "AIzaSyCOLAYwS2P3ELqnTiPs3VPHGquQy1UoEIQ";

    // This is a *cheat*  It is a hard-coded registration ID from an Android device
    // that registered itself with GCM using the same project id shown above.
    private static final String ANDROID_DEVICE = "APA91bEF-_Y7t3Vc59OGuK9gnBWDegE4g2KyVgNeVIZbjGWe-4b9FMHrL82oOEYRPVz7_GaCOHbq3PatsuU_pk8jhvGng3Xp-CAv48iPqamer8Y2aajyTvUho9hsy39uNudA8XI4ML09eUsPNH87zcuGc_v2uJj65g";

    // This array will hold all the registration ids used to broadcast a message.
    // for this demo, it will only have the ANDROID_DEVICE id that was captured 
    // when we ran the Android client app through Eclipse.
    private List<String> androidTargets = new ArrayList<String>();

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public GCMBroadcast() {

        super();

        // we'll only add the hard-coded *cheat* target device registration id 
        // for this demo.
        androidTargets.add(ANDROID_DEVICE);

    }

    // This doPost() method is called from the form in our index.jsp file.
    // It will broadcast the passed "Message" value.
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // We'll collect the "CollapseKey" and "Message" values from our JSP page
        String collapseKey = "";
        String userMessage = "";

        try {
            userMessage = request.getParameter("Message");
            collapseKey = request.getParameter("CollapseKey");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        // Instance of com.android.gcm.server.Sender, that does the
        // transmission of a Message to the Google Cloud Messaging service.
        Sender sender = new Sender(SENDER_ID);

        // This Message object will hold the data that is being transmitted
        // to the Android client devices.  For this demo, it is a simple text
        // string, but could certainly be a JSON object.
        Message message = new Message.Builder()

        // If multiple messages are sent using the same .collapseKey()
        // the android target device, if it was offline during earlier message
        // transmissions, will only receive the latest message for that key when
        // it goes back on-line.
        .collapseKey(collapseKey)
        .timeToLive(30)
        .delayWhileIdle(true)
        .addData("message", userMessage)
        .build();

        try {
            // use this for multicast messages.  The second parameter
            // of sender.send() will need to be an array of register ids.
            MulticastResult result = sender.send(message, androidTargets, 1);

            if (result.getResults() != null) {
                int canonicalRegId = result.getCanonicalIds();
                if (canonicalRegId != 0) {

                }
            } else {
                int error = result.getFailure();
                System.out.println("Broadcast failure: " + error);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // We'll pass the CollapseKey and Message values back to index.jsp, only so
        // we can display it in our form again.
        request.setAttribute("CollapseKey", collapseKey);
        request.setAttribute("Message", userMessage);

        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }

}
```

1. Since it is a web service, it does not have android_manifest.xml. So permission for internet cannot be added.
2. If I want to change the host(android.googleapis.com), then how should I do it. (it seems broken).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to turn off your firewall? You have to enable gcm ports.

> If your organization has a firewall that restricts the traffic to or
>   from the Internet, you need to configure it to allow connectivity with
>   GCM. The ports to open are: 5228, 5229, and 5230. GCM typically only
>   uses 5228, but it sometimes uses 5229 and 5230. GCM doesn't provide
>   specific IPs, so you should allow your server to accept incoming
>   connections from all IP addresses contained in the IP blocks listed in
>   Google's ASN of 15169.

BTW GCM message request is a simple http post, without Message Builder you have to post a message in json format.

[Android developer site](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/c2dm.html)
[More information about message fields](http://www.londatiga.net/featured-articles/how-to-send-message-to-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-server-using-json-and-php/)

Comment: do you know how can we edit the host link for a web service in tomcat?

Comment: I don't really know. You can try a php version. Source code is downloadable. 

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: error is partially solved 
and there is a contant.java named file in gcm_server where u can change the host name

Comment: @tinos07 Can you please tell me how did you solve that error ?
I'm getting the same exception at this line
<code> Result result = sender.send(message, registrationId, 5);</code>

I am implementing it under corporate Firewall, but I have opened those particular ports. Earlier I was not able to get the regId from GCM Server because ports were blocked, but now I can receive the regId - I guess that means required ports have been opened properly.  Can you please tell me How did you solve the problem ? Also I couldn't find any contact.java file. I'm using the demo code available in developer site.

Comment: @chimu :: implementation under corporate fire wall is not possible . m afraid that u have to do it on an open network . and the working is is really quick and time saving .Content .java is present in gcm_server folder